# Ruby -Reconstructing Hash from modified values

Tags: ruby

I am writing a program which will scan a directory, take the checksums of the lines in the file, and compare it to some database, returning the matching entries.

My database is a json file containing file names and the checksums for their lines and it looks like this:

```
"HASHES": {
   "file_name": {
     "1": "checksum",
     "2": "checksum"
   },
   "file_name": {
     "1": "checksum",
     "2": "checksum
   },
   etc..
}
```

I then scan a directory and and construct a similar hash (i.e a hash of file_name, line number, checksum). This code works.

The problem I have is reconstructing a similar hash from the results

This is the code I have:

```
def compare(dir_hash, database_hash)
  temp_hash     = database_hash.dup

  # retrieve the checksums from the dir_hash.
  dir_values    = dir_hash["HASHES"].sort_by(&:first).map { |x| x.last.values }

  # retrieve the checksums from database_hash
  db_values     = database_hash["HASHES"].sort_by(&:first).map { |x| x.last.values }

  # perform a set intersection to get the common values
  unique_values = dir_values.zip(db_values).map { |x| x.reduce(:&) }

  # code to reconstruct hash, based on new values
  new_hash      = temp_hash["HASHES"]

end
```

I can't seem to figure out how to reconstruct the hash with the modified values.

Help appreciated.

**Note**

The purpose of the `sort_by(&:first)` is to ensure that when we perform the set intersection, that we are performing it on the same value, in other words, I take the set intersection of file `x` from the directory and the same file `x` from the database (due to the fact that Ruby does not preserve order of keys)

Since `sort_by` will return an array, the first element will be the file_name, and the second element will be the hash of line number, checksum

Comment: Can you please add a sample input for dir_hash and database_hash and what you want the reconstructed hash with modified values to look like for them?

Comment: You need the intersection of two hashes then, right ? both keys and values ?

Comment: @Sid the database_hash and dir_hash would look like the hash I have in my question.  Just, with real information.  Essentially, the JSON file (database) looks like the hash in the question, and when I scan the directory, I create a hash which looks identical (i.e `filename => { :1 => :checkusm, :2 => :checksum, :3 => :checksum}}` The only difference would be the values (i.e filenames and checksums)

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk Yes, if 2 keys are identical, then I want to take the intersection of the values for that key, then have the value for that key be the new values from the intersection, maintaining the information (line numbers and checksum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can do this:

```
intersect_ary = database_hash["HASHES"].keys & dir_hash["HASHES"].keys
new_hash = dir_hash
intersect_ary.each do |file|
  new_hash["HASHES"][file].select! {|key| new_hash["HASHES"][file][key] == database_hash["HASHES"][file][key]}
end
```

(Assuming you must create a new hash rather than just mutate `dir_hash`)

Comment: hmm, for some reason, I am getting results like `filename => {"1" => nil, "2" => nil, "3" => nil}}`

Comment: although, changing it to `new_hash[:HASHES][file].select { |key| new_hash[:HASHES][file][key] == database_hash[:HASHES][file][key] }` seems to work

Comment: Actually that was to create a new_hash of `{"HASHES"=>{"file1"=>{"1"=>"1", "2"=>"3"}, "file2"=>{"1"=>"2", "2"=>"4"}}}` but I see that I missed you wanting only the intersection key-value pairs, so in that case use `select` as you said!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the correct output should look like for your question, but I'm working on a library that's designed to make it easier to work with nested collections, so I thought I'd give it a stab. Is this what you had in mind?

Note: This solution relies on the code in https://github.com/dgopstein/deep_enumerable

```
require './deep_enumerable/lib/deep_enumerable.rb'

dir_hash = {
  "HASHES": {
     "file1": {
       "1": "1",
       "2": "2"
     },
     "file2": {
       "1": "3",
       "2": "4"
     }
  }
}

database_hash = {
  "HASHES": {
     "file1": {
       "1": "1",
       "2": "3"
     },
     "file2": {
       "1": "2",
       "2": "4"
     }
  }
}

p dir_hash.deep_intersect(database_hash)
=> {:HASHES=>{:file1=>{:"1"=>"1"}, :file2=>{:"2"=>"4"}}}
```

Or without the library (untested outside of this one example):

```
def deep_intersect(this, other, &block)
  empty = this.select{false}

  (this.keys + other.keys).each do |key|
    s_val = (this[key] rescue nil)
    o_val = (other[key] rescue nil)

    comparator = block || :==.to_proc

    if s_val.is_a?(Hash) && o_val.is_a?(Hash)
      int = deep_intersect(s_val, o_val, &block)
      if !int.empty?
        empty[key] = int
      end
    elsif comparator.call(s_val, o_val)
      empty[key] = s_val
    end
  end

  empty
end


p deep_intersect(dir_hash, database_hash)
=> {:HASHES=>{:file1=>{:"1"=>"1"}, :file2=>{:"2"=>"4"}}}
```

Comment: Although, I was hoping to find a solution which wouldn't rely on a library.

Comment: Yeah, libraries are the worst... I've added a vanilla Ruby implementation.